# ApplyForce ineffective after affected body has been still for a while

Tags: c++, box2d

I am playing with Box2D for the first time. I have built a simple test application which consists of a static body representing the ground and a small, dynamic box, which falls and lands on the former. I then decided to experiment with forces, assigning a key to cause an upward force to be applied to the box. It works as expected, but only if I make sure to trigger the force before the box has been completely still for some instants. Is this behavior expected?

FWIW, here is how the body, shape and fixture of the dynamic box are defined:

```
b2BodyDef body_def;
body_def.type = b2_dynamicBody;
body_def.position.Set(position.x, position.y);
body = world.CreateBody(&body_def);

b2PolygonShape shape;
shape.SetAsBox(size.width / 2.0f, size.height / 2.0f);

b2FixtureDef fixture_def;
fixture_def.shape = &shape;
fixture_def.density = 1.0f;
fixture_def.friction = 0.3f;
```

This is the code that applies the upward force:

```
b2Body* body = box.b2_body();
body->ApplyForce(b2Vec2(0.0f, 15.0f), body->GetPosition(), false);
```

And this is the simulation step call:

```
world.Step(time_step, velocity_iterations, position_iterations);
```

where:

- `time_step` is 1/60
- `velocity_iterations` is 6; and
- `position_iterations` is 2.

If any further information is needed, just let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Box2D, like most physics engines, will "put objects to sleep" if they don't move for a while. This saves calculations. You need to wake up the object if you want it to continue moving.

```
body->ApplyForce(b2Vec2(0.0f, 15.0f), body->GetPosition(), false);
```

The third parameter to `ApplyForce` tells Box2D whether it should be allowed to wake the object up. You have told Box2D not to wake the object up. Change this parameter to true.